# How do I get Chrome/Chromium to remember username and password for Namecheap?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, autocomplete

I've tried some extensions like "Autocomplete on" and "Remember Password", but nothing seems to on just this particular site.  All other sites seem to be working fine without extensions.

Is there a way to force a password save on a particular box?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the LastPass extension on the site and it works just fine. If you want to do it with the built-in password manager have you tried going to: https://www.namecheap.com/myaccount/login.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Click the key in the right hand side of the URL bar.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: I had this same issue, and came here also looking for an answer. After going to namecheap and entering in my username and password, there is a key in the URL bar and when I clicked it, the username was listed and it allowed me to enter the password the second time.  Now when I go Namecheap, if it doesn't auto-fill, I can just click on the key icon and then that will autofill it.  Also, my original comment was marked deleted by someone for some reason.  I have a screenshot of the icon, but not sure how to paste it here.